# Jackson Serialization of an Arraylist of objects with variable key

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, swagger

I'm using a few different POJO's to generate a swagger API spec. However, I'm having an issue when trying to format the JSON properly.

Currently the response looks like this:

## Resulting JSON

```
 {
   "parameters": {
      "regionid": {
         "description": "Region ID for Regional Assignment",
         "required": false,
         "type": "integer",
         "format": "int32"
       },
      "timeperiodid": {
         "description": "School year time period",
         "required": false,
         "type": "integer",
         "format": "int32"
       }
    }
}
```

## Resulting Yaml

```
parameters:
    regionid:
      description: Region ID for Regional Assignment
      required: false
      type: integer
      format: int32
    timeperiodid:
      description: School year time period
      required: false
      type: integer
      format: int32
```

Instead of the correct format (ArrayList of objects):

## Expected JSON

```
 {
   "parameters": [
    {
      "regionid": {
         "description": "Region ID for Regional Assignment",
         "required": false,
         "type": "integer",
         "format": "int32"
       }
    },
    {
      "timeperiodid": {
        "description": "School year time period",
        "required": false,
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
```

## Expected Yaml

```
parameters:
    - regionid:
        description: Region ID for Regional Assignment
        required: false
        type: integer
        format: int32
    - timeperiodid:
        description: School year time period
        required: false
        type: integer
        format: int32
```

Method Class Which wraps and returns the parameters:

```
 public class Method {
   @JsonIgnore
   private String method;

   private HashMap<String, Parameter> parameters;
```

Parameter Object Class:

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 public class Parameter {
   @JsonIgnore
   private String name;

   private String in;

   private String description;

   private boolean required;

   private String type;

   private String format;
```

Comment: To me "regionid:" looks better in JSON format than "- regionid:". Why is that dash?

Comment: @Juvanis thanks. That was the YAML format of the pased JSON. I've added the actual JSON to the description for clarity.

Comment: can you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parameters` object has an array in it.  The type of object in that array look like a key/Parameter, so you'll need to model a `Map<String, Parameter>` as the array items.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this line:

```
private HashMap<String, Parameter> parameters;
```

to

```
private HashMap<String, Parameter[]> parameters;
```

as you map "regionid" to an array of parameters, not to just one parameter.

Comment: No I don't think that's it. Parameters is an array of objects, each object is the parameter name mapped to a list of attributes (description, type, format, etc). My issue is getting a variable value as the root key for the object